# Total distribution of m geometric distributions

Tags: distributions, expected-value, discrete-data, geometric-distribution, coupon-collector-problem

Suppose that you made a webpage and you are collecting the statistics from
the visitors. There are m types of visitors (students, company recruiters, etc.). Each visit is
equally likely to be any of the m types, independent of the types of previous visitors. Find
the expected number of visitors needed in order to have at least one of each type.

This is a homework question.
As far as I know, let just say the number of each visitor is X_i, and it is geometrically distributed with p=1/m
Let's call the number of visitor needed X: X = sum(X_i)
The problem is, what is the distribution of X.

Comment: This is known as the coupon collector problem. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

For the number of visits needed: http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/Coupon.html

Comment: Since it is homework you need a self-study tag.

Comment: This is an accessible paper:  http://mat.uab.cat/matmat/PDFv2014/v2014n02.pdf